# Is it possible to enumerate for all permutations of two IEnumerables using linq

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, permutation

I could do this using loops, but is there a way to take two IEnumerables, enumerate through all possible permutations and select an object that contains the permutation?  I feel like this 'should' be possible but am not really sure what operators to use.

Thanks
James

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you talking about what is basically a cartesian join? You can do something like

```
var query = from item1 in enumerable1
            from item2 in enumerable2
            select new { Item1 = item1, Item2 = item2 }
```

Comment: This is probably the way to go to get all permutations - just keep in mind it is O(n*m). However, if you want just a single permutations (say a random one), you are better off using `ElementAt()` on each list with a random index to produce that permutations.

Answer (score 6):

[Anthony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629705/is-it-possible-to-enumerate-for-all-permutations-of-two-ienumerables-using-linq/2629717#2629717) is correct. The extension method equivalent is:

```
var query = enumerable1.SelectMany(
                x => enumerable2,
                (item1, item2) => new { Item1 = item1, Item2 = item2 }
            );
```

or

```
var query = enumerable1.SelectMany(
                item1 => enumerable2.Select(item2 => 
                    new { Item1 = item1, Item2 = item2 });
            );
```